# Is it possible to reconnect a severed tree trunk and save a tree?

Tags: botany, trees

I ask this question because I saw in a the news recently (September 28, 2023) that some vandal cut down the famous [Sycamore Gap Tree](https://Sycamore%20Gap%20Tree)

[image]

I know people normally don't put trees back together, but from what little I know about plant biology and tree trunks, I thought it might be possible, with some extra effort. The inner part of the tree is dead wood anyway, so perhaps that could be fused with internal steel rods, sort of like how surgeons use metal to align broken leg bones. Then, perhaps, the sap-carrying outer layer, under the bark, could be realigned and protected in some way so that it could grow back together?

Has it ever been done? Do you think it could be possible?

Comment: Potentially, but the forces involved with a tree in wind are enormous, so I don't think it would work. Not certain though - grafting is certainly possible on trees.

Comment: I would try reattaching it with an specialized bioreactor pumping some nutrient medium, do periodic analysis, readjust nutrient input, etcetera, but it would cost a lot only doing the very much needed previous research on the topic. Maybe some A-Team of biotechnologists and physicists could pull it off.

Comment: I asked a similar question which was closed as a duplicate.  But my question really is, why does this not appear to even have been considered?  I get that there are challenges and it would be expensive, but for something that touches the public to this extent why not at least try?   Is it known impossible for some reason? https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/113166/why-couldnt-grafting-save-the-sycamore-gap-tree

Comment: Maybe because Northumberland council is cash-strapped, but that'd be a question to ask them. @CrashGordon