# Why couldn't grafting save the Sycamore Gap tree?

Tags: trees

The Sycamore Gap tree in England was recently cut down by a vandal.  There is hope that the tree can be "saved" by nursing shoots that are hoped to come up from the roots.

Grafting is routinely done to propagate desirable trees by attaching branches to the root of a more hardy tree.  In these cases, the pieces being grafted come from two different individuals.  (Or more; my grandfather had an apple/pear/rose tree with dozens of types on a single root.)

So why is grafting not considered when a single individual is involved?  It seems to me (who has never grafted anything) that it should be possible to place a support (e.g. sturdy non-corroding metal bar) in the middle of the stump to replace the mechanical strength of the wood, then set the entire tree back upon it and allow it to graft back together.

Certainly this would be an expensive undertaking for a large tree, and would not be guaranteed to work.  But for a tree of such historical significance, there must be some reason that it wasn't even tried.

What am I missing?